# Github gist page won't load in iframe

Tags: html, iframe, github, gist

I want to list all my gists on a single page and an iframe seemed like the quickest and easiest solution, the problem is that it won't load. My example show the same html used to make gist.github.com and google.com show in an iframe. Google will load but github won't.

Is this a limitation that Github imposes, is there a better way to list embed all my gists on a single page without adding each gist individually? I want it to show up automatically when I create a new one.

http://jsfiddle.net/guanome/VGEjB/1/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Considering GitHub won't let you display its content with a frame, lime Rob mention in his answer (+1 btw), you could consider using the [GitHub Api for Git](http://developer.github.com/v3/gists/).

That way, you build your own content.

Comment: The API looks like the best method to get the gists and, like you said, I can display the content however I want after that.

Answer (score 17):

Github has added the `X-Frame-Options: deny` HTTP header, which prevents the page from being embedded in a page (such as a frame).

See also: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/The_X-FRAME-OPTIONS_response_header

Comment: Is there any other way to simply display all my gists on another page?

Comment: There is no reliable way to directly display your gists in the page. I'd suggest caching your gist, e.g. by perdiodically requesting the page via a server-side (eg PHP) script. Then, include your gists in the frame, with a link to the current page at gist + time of retrieval.

Answer (score 0):

Forgive me, because I am a big newbie - but I may have a solution.

Couldn't you download the webpage down to local and then add that to the server that you're hosting as a resource. Then, just add an href to the actual github.

Or alternatively,

possibly change the webpage to a pdf/png, using a webpage to pdf/png extension. Then use the  of the pdf/png. I did this and it worked for me, unfortunately it's static and won't be up-to-date.